# Value in object is lost angular ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

I try to get value from store by key `words`:

```
  this.store.subscribe(store => {
    console.log('Store 1', store);
    console.log('Store 2', store.words);
  })
```

[image]

Why value is `undefind` in second case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you named your state as `state`, but you're trying to access its `words` slice directly from the global object.

You have to access it as: `store.state.words`

Answer (score 0):

Amer thanks a lot for your answer

Yes I named my `state` like `state`.

```
StoreModule.forRoot({
  state: MyReducer,
}),
```

Also I did mistake in generic type in construntor.

Below right decision:

```
StoreModule.forRoot({
  state: UserWordReducer,
}),

private store: Store<{state: AppState}
```